# Integration tests with Azure Hybrid Connection

Tags: azure, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-hybrid-connections

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that sends HTTP requests to on-prem resources. This is made possible by [adding Hybrid Connections to the App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#add-and-create-hybrid-connections-in-your-app) (under "Networking"). This works fine.

I added [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) which call my API endpoints. When I run these tests in the Azure DevOps pipeline, obviously these on-prem resources are unavailable because there are no Hybrid Connection involved.

Can I configure the `WebApplicationFactory` to use Hybrid Connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the pipeline on a self-hosted agent instead. Then my on-prem resources are available.